# SVM with python and CPLEX, load the quadratic part of the objective function

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, linear-programming, cplex

''In general, it would get better performance creating batches of linear constraints rather than creating them one at a time. I just wondering if it states even with a huge problem.'' - The wise programmer.

To be clear, I have a (35k x 40) dataset, and I want to do SVM on it. I need to produce the Gramm matrix of this dataset, it is fine, but to pass the coefficient to CPLEX is a mess, it takes hours, here my code:

```
    nn = 35000
    XXt = np.random.rand(nn,nn) # the gramm matrix of the dataset
    yy = np.random.rand(nn)     # the label vector of the dataset

    temp = ((yy*XXt).T)*yy
    xg, yg = np.meshgrid(range(nn), range(nn))
    indici = np.dstack([yg,xg])

    quadraric_part = []
    for ii in xrange(nn):
        for indd in indici[ii][ii:]:
            quadraric_part.append([indd[0],indd[1],temp[indd[0],indd[1]]])
```

The 'quadratic_part' is a list of the form [i,j,c_ij] where c_ij is the coefficient stored in temp. It will be passed to the function 'objective.set_quadratic_coefficients()' of the CPLEX Python API.

There is a wiser way to do that?

P.S. I have maybe a Memory problem, so It wold be better, instead store the whole list 'quadratic_part', call several times the function 'objective.set_quadratic_coefficients()'.... you know what I mean?!

Comment: No real answer, but why using general-solvers when customized solvers will be much more efficient ([e.g. using this approach](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_custom_kernel.html))? One obvious speedup would be using a pre-allocated quadratic_part array.

Comment: Have you tried using objective.set_quadratic instead?

Comment: I read the post, scikit would not work for my purpose because I need to solve the mip linked to SVM using the so called 'indicator constraint', which are implemented in CPLEX.


What should I feed into 'objective.set_quadratic'? Could you write down a small example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the hood, [objective.set_quadratic](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/cplex._internal._subinterfaces.ObjectiveInterface-class.html#set_quadratic) makes use of the [CPXXcopyquad](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcallablelibrary/qpapi/copyquad.html?pos=3) function in the C Callable Library.  Whereas, [objective.set_quadratic_coefficients](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSA5P_12.7.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/cplex._internal._subinterfaces.ObjectiveInterface-class.html?view=kc#set_quadratic_coefficients) uses [CPXXcopyqpsep](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcallablelibrary/qpapi/copyqpsep.html?pos=3).

Here is an example (bear in mind that I am not a numpy expert; it's quite possible there's a better way to do that part):

```
import numpy as np
import cplex

nn = 5  # a small example size here

XXt = np.random.rand(nn,nn) # the gramm matrix of the dataset
yy = np.random.rand(nn)     # the label vector of the dataset
temp = ((yy*XXt).T)*yy

# create symetric matrix
tempu = np.triu(temp)     # upper triangle
iu1 = np.triu_indices(nn, 1)
tempu.T[iu1] = tempu[iu1] # copy upper into lower

ind = np.array([[x for x in range(nn)] for x in range(nn)])

qmat = []
for i in range(nn):
    qmat.append([np.arange(nn), tempu[i]])

c = cplex.Cplex()
c.variables.add(lb=[0]*nn)
c.objective.set_quadratic(qmat)
c.write("test2.lp")
```

Your Q matrix is completely dense so depending on the amount of memory you have, this technique may not scale.  When it's possible, though, you should get better performance initializing your Q matrix with `objective.set_quadratic`.  Perhaps you'll need to use some hybrid technique where you use both `set_quadratic` and `set_quadratic_coefficients`.

Comment: Very nice way to do cplex along with python! set_quadratic was the function I was looking for

Comment: Maybe you have an hint for this question too, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41962488/decomposition-of-matrices-for-cplex-and-machine-learning-application?noredirect=1#comment71104913_41962488